# Inside a trigger create database is not working

Tags: sql-server-2005

I tried using trigger concept. If any new row inserts in the user table my trigger will fire and try to create a dynamic database for that new user. But Inside a trigger create database is not working. How can get it done. Can anybody have any suggestions.Please help of on this

Comment: I'm not certain, but I would wager you're not allowed to run DDL (Database Definition Language) statements inside of triggers -- it would seem to me to be an invitation for security holes...

Answer (score 10):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) says (under **Trigger Limitations**):

> The following Transact-SQL statements are not allowed in a DML trigger: 
>   (...) CREATE DATABASE (...)

There are further limitations, consulting the documentation is highly recommended.

This all means, to my understanding, that you should solve this problem at application level<sup>*</sup>: check whether your user is successfully created, and then issue a `CREATE DATABASE` statement.  Preferably these two are enclosed in a transaction, so that either both succeed or both fail - this way you can be sure that your data are in a consistent state.  You may have to issue a `DROP DATABASE` if the transaction fails.  (Thanks to Jon Seigel for pointing this out.)

<strike>*: From this point of view, the 'application' may be a T-SQL block of code (or a stored procedure) as well.</strike>

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE` can't be put in a user transaction because it affects things outside the database engine. See the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx). I agree with the rest of your answer, though, so +1.

Comment: @JonSeigel Thanks for your notice.  Does this mean that you can't even enclose it in a transaction started by a database abstraction layer?

Comment: A DAL merely *abstracts* the database operations, it doesn't perform any special behaviour. In theory, a DAL could roll it back, but it would have to be coded to manually execute a `DROP DATABASE` command, as a `ROLLBACK` won't work.

Answer (score 6):

You do not want to provision a seat for your new tenant in a DML trigger. For one, provisioning is usually lengthy and you do not want to block the DML, and likely the HTTP request for new user onboarding behind it. You want to be able to create and onboard the user, then start the provisioning process. If the provisioning goes awry, you can resolve the problem with offline intervention later, and you have the user record to contact and to notify that the account is now properly provisioned (ie. you do not lose a customer). The second reason is the problem you run into, namely that some provisioning operations are simply not do-able from a DML trigger, and as things will evolve and your architecture becomes more complex the provisioning will become more complex (eg. load balance the account resources).

The universal solution is to decouple the two and use queues. The account creation drops a message into a queue to request provisioning the account. A queue monitoring process kicks off (after the user account is committed!) and does the necessary work, asynchronously. SQL Server can handle this via [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) and [internal activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This is much better than doing it at application level because is reliable (ie. if the user stops the page load during the account creation, which in turn triggers a cancellation of the application processing the HTTP request, it does not leave an orphaned non-provisioned account).

Comment: Very important points!

Answer (score 0):

I would question this whole design.  Even if you could create a database, it won't be being backed up, so what's the point of it?

Is there any reason your user needs a whole database?  How about just having normal tables, with a userId or userName column, so if there is user-specific data they need, they can just query the relevant table filtered by userId/name.

This has a number of advantages, including (presumably) your database being backed up and maintained as part of a regular maintenance plan, non-proliferation of the same objects over multiple databases.

Have you mentioned this design to your DBA?  I'd be keen to know what they think.

Comment: There definitely are multi-tenant databases around, just think of SaaS.

Comment: Both approaches (shared db vs. 1 db per tenant) have pros and cons. Think about systems where tenants can opt in for schema upgrades. Shared db. and scoped queries ([act_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) like) tend to be favored  at the low end spectrum, while 1 db per tenant tends to be favored at the enterprisey high end of the spectrum. All in all is a separate debate though. And btw provisioning that configures maintenance (ie. regularly backs up the account db) are rather the norm than the exception.